# Sorting Arrays In Java soicanpost

Tags: java, arrays

my question is how would I sort the arrayofnames and arrayofdownloads so they're in ascending order and each name matches with it corresponding number of downloads. i've been trying for 4 hours and i can't seem to wrap my head around it

thanks

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class short6 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] arrayofnames = new String[4];
        int[] arrayofdownloads = new int[4];

        printmessage(arrayofnames, arrayofdownloads);
        details(arrayofnames, arrayofdownloads);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void printmessage(String[] arrayofnames, int[] arrayofdownloads)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int totalDownloads = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayofnames.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("What is track " + (i + 1));
            arrayofnames[i] = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("How many thousands of times has it been downloaded? ");
            arrayofdownloads[i] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        Arrays.sort(arrayofnames);
        Arrays.sort(arrayofdownloads);

        System.out.println("The track downloaded the most is " + arrayofdownloads[0]+".");
    }

    public static void details(String[] arrayofnames, int[] arrayofdownloads)
    {
        int totaldownloads = IntStream.of(arrayofdownloads).sum();
        System.out.println("The track downloaded the most is " + arrayofdownloads[0]+".");
        System.out.println("The total number of downloads of these 4 tracks was " + totaldownloads * 1000 +".");

        System.out.println("\nThe details of the downloads are");

        for (int i = 1; i < arrayofnames.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(arrayofnames[i]);
            System.out.println((arrayofdownloads[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you bound to use with array or we can use any collection?

Comment: thank you so much for the response, I am very new to programming so i find it hard to understand what you suggested but i will give it a go anyway

Comment: yeah i'm trying to make it work using only arrays

Answer (score 2):

I'd start creating a Song (e.g.) class that contains both the song name, and the number of downloads:

```
public class Song {

  private String name;

  private int downloads;

  public Song(String name, int downloads) {
    this.name = name;
    this.downloads = downloads;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public int getDownloads() {
    return this.downloads;
  }

}
```

And then, create an array of songs:

```
Song[] arrayOfSongs = new Song[4];
```

And load it from the input:

```
arrayOfSongs[i] = new Song(scanner.nextLine(), Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()));
```

Now you just need to sort it using a comparator:

```
Arrays.sort(arrayOfSongs, new Comparator<Song> () {
            public int compare(Song o1, Song o2) {
                // Sorting by name              
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }

        });
```

Or, as @Benoit has said in the comments, it would be even easier this way (Java 8 or up):

```
Arrays.sort(arrayOfSongs, Comparator.comparing(Song::getName));
```

And your done, just printing the objects (a toString method can be helpful here) you have the information sorted.

Edit: to read the input writing the questions, you just need to store the values in variables e.g.

```
System.out.println("What is track " + (i + 1));
String songName = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("How many thousands of times has it been downloaded? ");
int songDownloads = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
arrayOfSongs[i] = new Song(songName, songDownloads);
```

Or you can just implement setter methods in the Song class and create a constructor with no parameters, so you can set the values as you are reading them.

Comment: Or even better:
`Arrays.sort(arrayOfSongs, Comparator.comparing(Song::getName));`

Comment: Absolutely agree @Benoit

Comment: would anyone care to explain how to take the users input and put it in the downloads and songname field for song type.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply, so I've figured that i can use a for loop to ask the questions for song name and number of downloads. what im finding hard is putting their response in each array from 1-4 and saving dong name in the correct field of the song record and same for number of downloads?

```
public static void printmessage(song[] arrayOfSongs)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int totalDownloads = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfSongs.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("What is track " + (i + 1));
        // store in array x name field
        System.out.println("How many downloads does this track have? ");
        //store in array x downloads field
    }
```